# Subgroups of one-relator groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, one-relator-groups

I know that not every finitely-presented group may be embedded into a one-relator group, for example because of a theorem of Magnus stating that the word problem is solvable in one-relator groups. But does there is a great amount of finitely-generated groups embeddable into a one-relator group?

For instance, is there any (hopefully "large") class of groups known to be embeddable into a one-relator group?

Comment: I don't know if any hyperbolic group is known *not* to embed into any 1-relator group (I don't know either for $C'(1/6)$ f.p. groups). At the same time, I don't know if a 1-relator group may contain an infinite Property T subgroup.

Comment: PS the cohomological dimension fact mentioned by Carl in a comment to his answer seems to discard many hyperbolic groups.

Comment: The [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182528/subgroups-of-one-relator-groups#comment985341_386510) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182528/subgroups-of-one-relator-groups#comment985347_182528) by @YCor.

Comment: @YCor, see my comments on the answer below. Every infinite finitely generated subgroup of a one-relator group has infinite abelianisation. This rules out many 2-dimensional groups, including all with property T.

Comment: @HJRW Nice; actually I believe it would be a useful additional answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218422/

Comment: @YCor: I added it, as you suggest.

Answer (score 10):

There have been a couple of recent results which demonstrate that the class of subgroups of one-relator groups is very rich.  For instance, Calegari–Walker proved that a random 1-relator group contains a surface subgroup, and Calegari and I improved this by demonstrating that a random 1-relator group contains a subgroup isomorphic to the fundamental group of an acylindrical hyperbolic 3-manifold.  Both papers are on the arXiv.

A random 1-relator group is hyperbolic (since its relator satisfies the C'(1/6) small-cancellation condition) and 2-dimensional.  Results of Bowditch and Kapovich–Kleiner then impose certain restrictions on the (quasiconvex) subgroups that can arise—see the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135794) to [Topology of boundaries of hyperbolic groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135788/topology-of-boundaries-of-hyperbolic-groups) for some details.  In a sense, the above results show that the quasiconvex subgroups of random 1-relator groups are as rich as possible.  This is discussed in the introduction to our paper.

This leaves two strands uncovered.  A random 1-relator group will also contain non-quasiconvex finitely generated subgroups. (I think Dunfield–Thurston proved this in the 2-generator case.)  And, of course, plenty of 1-relator groups do not behave like a ‘random’ one—for instance, Baumslag's famous example of a non-abelian 1-relator group with every finite quotient cyclic.

Comment: A couple more comments.  These results are *not* embeddability results as asked for in the final paragraph of the question, in the sense that they don't say 'Every group of class X is embeddable into a 1-relator group', but rather 'A random 1-relator group contains a subgroup from class X'.  But the proof techniques *do* generate *a very large number* of subgroups of this form---a generic 1-relator group contains *many* 3-manifold groups as subgroups.

Comment: I changed 'no-abelian' to 'non-abelian', which I hope was correct.

Comment: It was! :)${}{}$

Answer (score 3):

It is known that a right-angled Artin group $A(\Gamma)$ embeds in some one-relator group if and only if $\Gamma$ is a forest. In fact, any such $A(\Gamma)$ embeds in the one-relator group $\operatorname{Gp}\langle a,t \mid [a, a^t] = 1\rangle$, which contains a copy of $A(P_4)$ (and hence also the group corresponding to any forest by certain embeddability results). This is all proved in *Gray, Robert D.*, [**Undecidability of the word problem for one-relator inverse monoids via right-angled Artin subgroups of one-relator groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00222-019-00920-2),  [ZBL07160162](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07160162).

Note that in the torsion case, the set of subgroups possible is significantly reduced, and explicit analysis can be done to a greater extent. For example, every $2$-generated subgroup of a $2$-generated one-relator group with torsion is either free or is itself a one-relator group with torsion. This is all possible by the B. B. Newman Spelling Theorem, which provides a significant degree of control. In particular, this theorem implies that one-relator groups with torsion are hyperbolic, so the only right-angled Artin groups embedding in some one-relator group with torsion are free. For detailed combinatorial analysis, and some more examples in the torsion case, see much of the work by Stephen Pride, e.g. *Pride, Stephen J.*, [**The two-generator subgroups of one-relator groups with torsion**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1997932), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 234, 483-496 (1977). [ZBL0366.20022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0366.20022).

Comment: The raag statement seems to include as particular case that $\mathbf{Z}^3$ doesn't embed into a 1-relator group.

Comment: @YCor Yes, but this already follows from the fact that the cohomological dimension of any torsion-free one-relator group is $\leq 2$.

Comment: I think most of these, and much more general, non-embeddability results can be extracted from recent work of Louder--myself, Helfer--Wise and Wise. In summary, we prove that every finitely generated, infinite subgroup of a one-relator group has Euler characteristic at most zero.  For a freely indecomposable RAAG, it follows the underlying graph is a tree...

Comment: ... For details, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2540, https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11976 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2579 . Much stronger results, which apply to many but not all one-relator groups, are proved in https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02671 .

Comment: (By the way, the point about RAAGs is just the observation that the Euler characteristic of a 2-dimenional RAAG defined by the graph $\Gamma$ is $1-\chi(\Gamma)$.)

Comment: Sorry for the extended comments. Looking at Gray's paper, I see that the non-embeddability result is in fact proved by appealing to out work, exactly as the above comments suggest!

Comment: @HJRW Yes, of course you're right. Thanks for writing this out! In fact, an earlier version of Bob's paper on the arXiv did not have that argument, after which Howie wrote to him to provide exactly that argument.